# AngularJS UI freeze during polling $timeout $scope updates

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have an app with a simple view that contains a list of a few items.

```
   <ion-view view-title="App">
    <ion-content>
        <div class="list">
            <div ng-repeat="group in groups">
                <div class="item item-divider">
                    {{group.name}}
                </div>
                <div class="item row" ng-repeat="item in group.items" ng-click="live(item.id)">
                    <div class="col-75">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

I fetch these items from a service that makes a $http get of a json array from the server, and inside the controller I need to update this list every 10 seconds.

```
.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state("home", {
            url: "/home",
            templateUrl: "home.html",
            controller: "homeCtrl",
            resolve: {
                data: function(appDataService){
                    return appDataService.getData();
                }
            }
        })

    ;
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/home");
});
    .factory('appDataService', function ($http) {
        return {
            getData: function () {
                return $http.get(HOST + "/ionic-proof.ashx").then(function (response) {
                    return response;
                });
            },
        };
    })

    .controller("homeCtrl", function($state, $scope, data, appDataService, $timeout){
        $scope.groups = data.data.groups;
        (function refresh(){
            appDataService.getData().then(function(response){
                $scope.groups = response.data.groups;
                $timeout(refresh, 10000);
            });
        })();
        $scope.live = function(id){
            $state.go("event", {id: id});
        };
    })
```

The problem is, everytime the $scope.groups inside the refresh() function is executed, I get a short "freeze" in the UI, which is quite noticeable (e.g. if I am scrolling the list up and down).

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How many items in `$scope.groups` there? Is it new data every time?

Comment: That might be you are having 1000 of records & due to `ng-repeat` rendering lag you are facing this issue..you could use `track by` to make `ng-repeat` smarter

Comment: Consider using $interval instead of $timeout also.

Comment: @NewDev not many really, around 50. It's not new everytime, but most of the time it is.

Comment: @PankajParkar it's only 50 items, so it should not affect performance

Comment: @ItaloAyres I do not want to do this since if there is a server lag I do not want to pile updates